# Need to generate N nodes. Stuck

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nodes

This is my node class:

```
public class Node 
{
    public int label;
    public boolean visited=false;
    public Node(int one)
    {
        this.label=one;
    }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do but it's giving me an error:

```
for(int n=0;n<=Nodes;n++)
{
    Node name+n = new Node(n);
}
```

Cannot convert node to  int. Is there any other way I can generate 4 different named nodes? This is a adjacency matrix to graph. Thanks!!!

Comment: `Node name+n` what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a collection.

Comment: Never ever make generated names (you actually can't do it in Java). Use arrays or other containers instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that it is giving an error is because you have a special character in an identifier. You could create an array of nodes and then use it as follows:

```
Node[] nodes = new Nodes[4]
for (int n=0; n < 4; n++) {
    nodes[n] = new Node(n);
}
```

Then you just need to reference the index in the nodes array to call them.

Comment: I just did. Finished my program thanks to this comment lol. 10hrs of coding FINISHED!